# The second div won't come back after it's clicked twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not really good at JQUERY, and I just tend to observe things, but here is a code I've been working on. So the goal here is that I want both **.people** and **.people_bg** to close when I click anywhere on my screen.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#relations").click(function(){
    $(".people").slideToggle("fast");
    $(".people_bg").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});


$('a.close, .people_bg').live('click', function() {
$('.people_bg , .people').fadeOut(function() {
$('.people_bg, a.close').remove(); //fade them both out
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

**The problem is:** It only works *once*. The second time around, only '.people' appears, and not '.people_bg'

Comment: That's probably happening because you're removing the elements from the page here: `$('.people_bg, a.close').remove()`. Comment out this line and try it.

Comment: The line `$('.people_bg, a.close').remove(); //fade them both out` will remove both `.people_bg` and `a.close` from the document, permanently. That's what jQuery's `remove` does, and that's why `.people_bg` can't re-appear. I guess that's not what you intended!

Comment: Also note that `.live()` has been deprecated as of jquery 1.7 : http://api.jquery.com/live/ You should use `.on()` now.

Answer (score 2):

The remove function that you're using actually deletes elements from the page altogether, so that's your culprit.  Replace that with a more appropriate function and you should be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply just `fadeOut` without `remove`. This will hide them without actually removing them from the page: [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpgqgmny/2/)

```
$('a.close, .people_bg').on('click', function () {
    $('.people_bg , .people').fadeOut();
});
```

Additionally, in your first function, you can combine the two class selectors:

```
$("#relations").click(function () {
    $(".people, .people_bg").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Also note that you should be using jquery's `.on()` as of version 1.7 instead of `.live()`.